# Binding Error in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I am building a simple tweet application and here is my code snippets. When running this app, I am getting the below error:

> EXCEPTION: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't
>   a known native property ("
>
> ```
>     <div *ngFor="#tweet of tweetList" >
>        <tweet [ERROR ->][data]="tweet"></tweet>        
>     </div>
> ```
>
> "): TweetsComponent@3:18

I did a search with this error, and have checked against all the root causes that could lead to this error, and it looks all fine to me.

Here is my components and services:

TweetService:

```
export class TweetService{

getTweetService() {

    return [
            {
                imageUrl: "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/?1",
                author: "Windward",
                handle:"@windwardstudios",
                tweetText:"Looking for a better company reporting or docgen app?"

            },
            {
                imageUrl: "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/?2",
                author: "AngularJS News",
                handle:"@angularjs_news",
                tweetText:"Right Relevance : Influencers, Articles and Conversations"

            },
            {
                imageUrl: "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/?3",
                author: "UX & Bootstrap",
                handle: "@3rdwave",
                tweetText: "10 Reasons Why Web Projects Fail"

            }
    ];
}
}
```

TweetsComponent:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {TweetService} from './tweet.service';
import {TweetComponent} from './tweet.component';
@Component({

selector:'tweets',
template:
`

    <div *ngFor="#tweet of tweetList" >
       <tweet [data]="tweet"></tweet>        
    </div>  

`,
providers: [TweetService],
directives: [TweetsComponent]
})

export class TweetsComponent{
tweetList;

constructor(tweetService: TweetService){

    this.tweetList = tweetService.getTweetService();
}

}
```

TweetComponent:

```
import {Component, Input } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({

selector:'tweet',
template:
`
<div class="media">
    <div class="media-left">
        <a href="#">
        <img class="media-object" src="{{ data.imageUrl }}" alt="media-object">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
        {{ data.author }} <span class="handle">{{ data.handle }}</span>
        {{ data.tweetText }}            
    </div>
</div>    
`,
styles:[
    `
    .media{
        margin-left: 30px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .handle{
        color: #ccc;
    }

    `
  ]
})

export class TweetComponent{
   constructor(){
       console.log(this.data)
   }
   @Input() data;

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a typo in `TweetsComponent`'s `directives`. You should pass in the class name of the TweetItemComponent (`TweetComponent`), not TweetListComponent (`TweetsComponent`). This is one of the reasons I prefer using "Item" and "List" explicitly instead of singular and plural forms.

Replace your TweetsComponent as following:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {TweetService} from './tweet.service';
import {TweetComponent} from './tweet.component';
@Component({
    selector:'tweets',
    template:
    `

        <div *ngFor="#tweet of tweetList" >
           <tweet [data]="tweet"></tweet>        
        </div>  

    `,
    providers: [TweetService],
    directives: [TweetComponent]
})
export class TweetsComponent{
    tweetList;

    constructor(tweetService: TweetService){
        this.tweetList = tweetService.getTweetService();
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah!! Such a small mistake and I was almost breaking my head for hours yesterday.....Thanks so much for pointing it out and also thanks for the tip on naming convention...I would surely follow this.

Comment: You're welcome mate. We all know that feeling when the whole system ceases to work because one missing character :)